# How to fetch all inbox messages in php in a dedicated server?

Tags: php, email, imap, bots, mail-server

In our application we need to connect to the user email inbox and fetch all of messages.
The application will run in a dedicated server by Ubuntu OS. 
I have ran some test in my pc by using imap extension (imap_open, imap_fetchheader, imap_fetchbody, ...).
There are multiple problems in using this approach:

1- The connection and fetching speed is very slow.

2- The php script will time out in case of many messages exists in inbox.

3- The application is multiuser and the number of requests is high.

My search results to solve above problems:

1- We have to rent a static IP from google or other email servers for imap connections !

2- We have to use PHP CLI to fetch orders from database and fetch inbox messages.

3- Multithreading in php.

Summary:

**I want to write a bot in php to Connect to mail servers everyday. What connection and fetching way do you suggest? (library, method, language and etc).** Thanks

**UPDATE : The code that I had ran to fetch 30 first messages:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}', 'myemailaddress', 'mypassword');

$count = imap_num_msg($mbox);

for($i = $count; $i >= $count - 30; $i--){
    $header = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $i);
    /* process header & body */
}

imap_close($mbox);
```

This code works well but when I change imap_fetchheader to imap_fetchbody it takes more time.

**Update** :
Based on the arkascha answer, I worked on my design and architecture and I found out the low speed reason is in the connections to the mail server. Because this is a I/O bounded task, I cached the imap connection to each mail server and the hole speed improved but not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your search results are simply wrong.

- you do not need a static IP address to fetch messages from an imap server. And certainly not one "rented from google". Why should that be required?
- I see no reasons why the cli variant of php should be better suited here. In contrary, it is less efficient, since it has a much bigger startup load bacause a process must be spawned for each and every request.
- why should you need multithreading? What benefits should it offer for this situation? Multithreading is only of interest for interactive stuff where responsiveness might be an issue. And even then this can be the wrong idea.

I myself implemented an imap client a few times and ran into no such problems. You certainly can implement a robust and efficient solution based on the phps imap extension. Speed of connection and transfer depend on many details, I doubt that php imap implementation is the cause of your problems. There might be additional issues which lead you to your statements, but you do not specify such in your question.

In general you should *never* fetch a huge list of data in one go and then process it. That is simply really bad design which *cannot* scale in any way. Instead you should always process lists in a sequential strategy: fetch a single data unit and process it. Then head on to the next. That way your memory footprint stays small, you prevent hitting php limits. This also enables you to process the whole list in smaller chunks (or even one message at a time) which prevents you from hitting phps execution time limit or a timeout on client side. These are general successful implementation patterns which are the base of a robust processing implementation which also apply to email messages.

To answer your bottom line question:

- nothing speaks against using phps imap extension
- use a cron job for this and do it on a regular base, not just once a day
- invest into planning a clean architecture before starting the implementation

Comment: I will not fetch whole emails at once because the number of inbox messages and its size is vary from a user to other user. The speed of whole task is very important. To fetch one email per a script run we need to use cron jobs. And PHP CLI script will manage the fetching process

Comment: Sorry, can't follow you there. Now _do_ you or _don't_ you plan to fetch all messages of a single user at once? Don't! Certainly you should use cron jobs if you want to process a bigger list of messages. This does _not_ mean you have to fetch the messages one by one, you could also process packages of maybe 100 messages in each script run. But clearly you _cannot implement mass processing on a synchronous and interactive approach_, it just won't work, you will run into problems again and again. And about cli: what should be the advantage?

Comment: PHP CLI stays up and dont close due to timeout and also it is not running by appache and works parallel. By using PHP CLI web server will be free to respond to user request

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. 1: the web server still handles the request, regardless if you use php as module, as fastcgi or as old fashioned cgi. 2: what does "parallel" mean here? an apache web server consists of many processes run in parallel anyway, so where is the difference? In contrary: you add a communication overhead which slows things down. 3: about the timeout: you are trying to fix the symptom instead of finding and fixing the cause of your problem. That is rarely a good strategy.

Comment: We have Multiple tasks like this, Do you suggest to write them in normal php script and schedule them by cron jobs?

Comment: It is all said above: use a cron job to trigger processing on a regular base, only process a fixed amount of messages in one script run, fetch, process and free the messages sequentially (one by one) instead of loading all messages into memory. The script will be more or less the same, regardless of which php execution strategy inside the web server you chose.

Comment: Ok, But there is a problem : For each message we have to establish a connection to Email server and after fetching close the connection, Assume 200000 message into an inbox, we have to connect to inbox and close the connection 200000 times, is it a correct approach?

Comment: You require only a single connection per script run. You can fetch the messages one by one reusing the same connection. Why do you think you have to close and reopen the connection? Don't! The number of messages you should retrieve in a single script run depends on many factors. You will have to make test runs and it probably makes sense to also react in a dynamical manner on runtime and performance issues.

Comment: How do we can reuse the connection established in previous script run?

Comment: Once more: you fetch _many_ messages in each script run. I stated that many times before.

Comment: Ok, "using cron jobs and fetching multiple messages in each script run", This is a good approach but assume we have other tasks too. Like connecting to social networks, web bots and etc, we can not implement all of them by cron jobs because it may cause to hang the web server and the application.

Comment: When I say you should fetch the messages "one by one" this does _not_ mean a single message in a script run! What I mean is this: you start the script, open the connection and then enter a loop. Inside the loop you fetch a message, process it, store or forward it or whatever and remove it again from the memory. Then you proceed with the next message until you reach some limit where you decide to terminate this script. Then you expunge the mailbox, close the connection and exit the script. That way your memory footprint stays small and the script can be scaled without problems.

Comment: The number of message you process in a single script run depends on many factors, which is why you have to test that out: connection speed, reaction speed of the server, size of single messages, since of message box in total, processing speed, speed of saving or forwarding the messages, deadlocks from things like logging to the file system, database efficiency, ...

Comment: Thankyou @arkascha. I think there is no solid reason to implement this  part of app by PHP CLI or anything else. Our main problem is the connecting and fetching speed. I have tested it and we can fetch only 5 or 6 message in each minute and I think we do something wrong

Comment: Then I suggest you post your code, append it to the question above, so that others can take a look and point out what the problem might be. Did you compare your results to another implementation? An ordinary email client maybe? Can you rule out that it is the _imap server_ being slow?

Comment: Yes exactly, connecting by imap_open takes 2 or 3 seconds and fetching email body or header for some email messages does not take much time but from some other takes about 20 seconds ! My test code connects by imap_open and gets messages count by imap_num_msg and fetch emails body and header by imap_fetchheader, imap_fetchboy in a loop

Comment: So what are those "some other"? No one here can help without you posting your code .

Comment: That obviously is not the real code, for example it overwrites `$header` in each iteration, so I assume this is just a demonstration of how you construct your loop. Certainly fetching bodies instead requires more time, but that is not an answer to my question or your own statement above, that "some other" takes much time. And it does not answer my question if it might be the _imap server_ which is slow. Why do you think it is your code that performs slow? You will have to make some profiling to get an answer, measuring the points of time of requests and answers against that imap server.

Comment: And, as said before, you can only make a statement about slow or fast if you compare your code to another implementation. I asked about whether you did compare it to some other client. _Did you?_ What is the result? What did you learn?

Answer (score 0):

I might be biased but I'd use Zend Framework with Zend_Mail_Storage classes: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.7/en/zend.mail.read.html You get a couple of options like switching to directly accessing mbox or maildir files if possible or getting closer to the underlying protocol and hack something in the zend_mail_protocol_imap to improve speed.